# How to find the path of media files that are related to a custom post in WordPress via MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How can I perform a query to find out the path (`/uploads/...jpg`) of the media files related to a specific post?

For example this is query I'm using to find out the id of my POST:

```
SELECT FROM wp_16_posts WHERE post_type = "new-rss" AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),post_date) > 60;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way attachments are related to other posts is when they are attached via the media library or uploaded to a post on the edit screen, they become children of that post.

So we can do a query based on the post_parent to find related media files and their paths.

```sql
SELECT m.post_id, m.meta_value AS 'file'
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS m ON p.id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key LIKE '_wp_attached_file' # Join postmeta to find the file path.
WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_parent = 1234 # Set the parent here.
```

Comment: Thank you sir appreciatte it